# making dendrogram manually in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, hierarchical-clustering, directed-graph, dendrogram

I'm using an algorithm to cluster a directed network hierarchically.my program is written recursively and in each step I make a group to two groups.(It's like a tree fractal)and I know which nodes have been separated in each level.Now I would like to draw it's dendrogram plot and to make it possible I have to provide something like linkage but because I bypass the pdist function so I can't use the linkage.Do you have any idea to help me provide the dendrogram plot based on my method?

Comment: You can build the matrix required by `dendrogram` and returned by `linkage` yourself, without relying on `linkage`, as specified for `Z` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linkage.html#zmw57dd0e392712).

Comment: But What if I have many nodes say 1000!It's really a bother to produce by yourself@Naveh

Comment: I don't see why size should be an issue. I meant you should write code to do it for you, not do it manually, obviously.